# htaccess redirection detecting integers in URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I need to redirect visits to either

- http://domainname.com/1234
- http://www.domainname.com/1234

to http://www.domainname.com/expanded_URL/file.jsp?=1234

So, I need to detect a URL with 1234 as number and redirect appropriately.

Is this possible with htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^/([0-9]+)$ ./expanded_URL/file.jsp?=$1
```

Maybe you should use L flag, for other cases.

[mod_rewrite - Variables Cheatsheet](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/mod_rewrite-variables-cheatsheet.html)